# Is there a way to limit the number of connection made by an IP address to my Windows Server?

Tags: windows, networking, security

Is there a way to limit the number of connection made by an IP address to my Windows Server?

I'm trying to restrict the number of connections used by a single IP address on my server

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? What are the connections doing - is the server hosting a website, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows doesn't have a built-in mechanism for doing this in the host firewall. It may be possible to configure specific applications to only allow a specific number of connections, but since you've provided no meaningful details, there's not much to work with.

Your best bet is to control this type of thing on a dedicated firewall box that the server is behind.

Comment: nice idea the windows server is VPS on Xen-Based Linux Server

Comment: windows server 2008
connection to Voice-Server and it doesn't have any option for limit connection per user